# Need help understanding the meaning of this

Tags: meditation-hindrances, jhana, five-hindrances

I am reading **A Critical Analysis Of The Jhanas**
In the book we were going over wise considration and how it will help you eliminate the hindrances. But i am having trouble understand what this is referring to. Any help would be appreciated.

> In the commentaries the Buddha’s miscellaneous suggestions on the elimination of the 
>   hindrances are organized into a systematic exposition of six measures conducive to the 
>   vanquishing of each hindrance. Sensual desire is to be abandoned by:
>
> Taking up the sensuously inauspicious subject of meditation; application for 
>   the development of the jhāna on the sensuously inauspicious subject of 
>   meditation; the guarded state of the controlling faculties of sense; moderation 
>   in food; the sympathy and support of good men in the endeavour; stimulating 
>   talk that helps the accomplishment of the object in view

What are they referring to i don't understand the wording?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to: [The Five Mental Hindrances and Their Conquest](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html#des)

> *Six things are conducive to the abandonment of sensual desire:*
>
> *1. Learning how to meditate on impure objects;*
>
> *2. Devoting oneself to the meditation on the impure;*
>
> *3. Guarding the sense doors;*
>
> *4. Moderation in eating;*
>
> *5. Noble friendship;*
>
> *6. Suitable conversation.*
>
> *— Commentary to the Satipatthana Sutta*

Comment: So is that passage just relating to this?